# What tense do I have to use in this sentence with 'whenever'?

Tags: past-tense, subjunctives

When I use 'would' with 'whenever', What tense is used? For example,

> Whenever I went to my grama's house, I would play in the park.

Can I use 'go to' instead of 'went to'?

Or

> I would dance whenever I felt bored.

I've heard that I have to use past tense in the subjunctive.
Is it right? Must I use only past tense in the subjunctive?

Answer (score 1):

In my thought, this sentence

Whenever I went to my grama's house, I would play in the park.

is correct. Because whenever-clause means the habit in the past, so we have two choices : use to
and would.

used to means the habit in the past and not doing in the present.

would means the habit in the past.